# Get only some elements from json with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have json is like this (excerpt):

```
[  
   {  
      "country":"Germany",
      "name":"Blabla",
      "address":"gsdfs",
      "address2":"",
      "city":"London",
      "state":"",
      "postal":"00100",
      "phone":"+2383 232",
      "email":"email@domain.com"
   },
   {  
      "country":"Germany",
      "name":"Blabla",
      "address":"gsdfs",
      "address2":"",
      "city":"London",
      "state":"",
      "postal":"90400",
      "phone":"+2383 232",
      "email":"email@domain.com"
   },
   {  
      "country":"United Kingdom",
      "name":"Blabla London",
      "address":"gsdfs",
      "address2":"",
      "city":"London",
      "state":"",
      "postal":"2984B746",
      "phone":"+2383 232",
      "email":"email@domain.com"
   },
   {  
      "country":"Japan",
      "name":"Blabla Tokyo",
      "address":"gsdfs",
      "address2":"",
      "city":"London",
      "state":"",
      "postal":"3455",
      "phone":"+2383 232",
      "email":"email@domain.com"
   }
]
```

Now I would like to get only the items in certain country. For example user click element that says get all german address so I would fetch the json and then print only the ones that are in germany.

My jQuery at the moment is like this (which prints just all address):

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'http://example/address.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, place) {
            places =
                "<ul>"
                    + "<li>"
                    + place.name
                    + "</strong></li>"
                    + "<li>"
                    + place.postal
                    + " "
                    + place.city
                    + "</li>"                               + "</ul>";
            $('#placesContainer').append(places);
        });
        console.log('ajax success');
    },
    error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('ajax error');
    }
});
```

Which works great but I would want to alter it to show only german stores (or what ever user selected).

Comment: Your options are either to filter server side (some kind of query by country functionality) or filter the results (ie. search through the json response and only return the part you want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check against what country you are filtering to,  and only append it if it matches the current place.

```
var country = "Germany";
...

success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, place) {
        if(place.country == country) {
            places =
                "<ul>"
                    + "<li>"
                    + place.name
                    + "</strong></li>"
                    + "<li>"
                    + place.postal
                    + " "
                    + place.city
                    + "</li>"                               + "</ul>";
            $('#placesContainer').append(places);
        }
    });
    console.log('ajax success');
}
```

Comment: While this is good, I'm not sure you would want to make an ajax request every time the user selects a different country

Comment: I was thinking way too difficult way this. Solution was simple! Thank you!

Comment: @Adjit, while you're correct, I didn't want to alter OP's code too much. It would probably be a better approach filter the data outside of the AJAX, but the same logic from my answer would apply

Comment: Oh good point @Adjit Will make change it that it will make only one request.